# Excel VBA: Use Lookup to locate and place phone # based on Name Selected

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I could use a bit of help with this, as i am new to Excel VBA. I have a two page workbook, and i would like to have help on some VBA code which places a phone # directly in the cell below, once a name is selected from a drop down list in the cell above. 
Names within in this drop down list will come from Col. A on the first sheet "Contacts", while the Phone #'s will come from Column B on the same Contacts Sheet.
My second sheet, "Schedule" is a large scheduling sheet, so i would want to run this code anytime a name is selected from this drop down list, regardless of the location of the cell on this sheet.
Any and all help on this would be greatly appreciated, as i am a bit stuck on this.
Thanks again so much,
Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: You have a sheet with the code name wshContacts.  On that sheet you have a list of names and you've named that range "ContactNames".  In the cells next to that range are the phone numbers.  On your schedule sheet, you have data validation drop down in some cells that points to the ContactNames named range.

Based on that, put this code in the schedule sheet's code module (right click on the sheet tab and choose View Code).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oValid As Validation
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim sRefersTo As String

    'The named range with your contact names
    Const sCNAMES As String = "ContactNames"

    Set oValid = Target.Validation

    'Trap error where there's no validation in cell
    On Error Resume Next
        sRefersTo = oValid.Formula1
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If it's a DV pointing to contact names
    If sRefersTo = "=" & sCNAMES Then
        'Find the name in the list
        Set rFind = wshContacts.Range(sCNAMES).Find(Target.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        'if the name was found
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            'put the next cell (phone number) in the cell below the changed cell
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = rFind.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This will run for every change that you make on the schedule sheet.  But it will only actually do something if the cell that was changed has data validation that points to the named range on your contacts sheet.

There are a couple of things to look out for.  This code doesn't contemplate changing multiple cells and it doesn't care if there's already something in the cell below (it overwrites it).  So you may have to adjust to handle those cases.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dick. I think that will work great. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi, I was able to figure out the issue as i had the written sheet name "Contacts" instead of the assigned sheet name "Sheet11" 
Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

Simple VLOOKUP formula will do this, no VBA is needed.

If the cell with the drop down is A1, then in A2 this formula might do the trick:

**=IF(A1="", "", VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!$A:$B, 2, 0))**

Comment: Thank you for that formula, however i need to keep all cells above and below 'available' for names, since it is a scheduler, and we wont be able to anticipate which time (row) they will use. VBA Code would allow then allow us to use any row, then automatically place the phone # below. Would you happen to be able to help me out with any VBA Code. Thanks again,Randy

Comment: Well....We have a column of available spots so users can enter appointmetns, say 1:00, 1:30, 2:00, 2:30. Each appointment is an hour. If we enter the name at 1:30, for a 1 Hr. Appointment, we no longer need the 2:00 time slot. We can then put useful information, like a phone # in that slot. We cant use a formula there, as we dont know exactly which time slot will be used originally. (NOTE:Each cell allows the user to enter any text, and not just what is available on the drop down list of contacts) Also users would not necessarrily schedule an appointment if a name already exists in a time slot